# Find sequential characters in a string within an array and replace them

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace

I have an array:
arr=['Hello World', 'Bye World', 'Useless World']

I would like to use Javascript tp find characters that are sequentially the same ("ss") and replace them with an *

Comment: That sounds like a good code challenge.  You should attempt it and ask a specific, code-based question when you get stuck.

Comment: I have been attempting it, as answers on here are very rarely clear or concise to most novices, any answers that I do get on here I am likely to have to work to decipher anyway, but thank you for your very useful input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be accomplished in many ways. But I would choose regex:

```
arr.map(function(item){ return item.replace(/(.)\1+/g, '*') } )
```

the map function will walk trough the array giving the function which it takes as a parameter one item at a time.
Because the items are string, you can call replace function on them.
I just supplied the replace function with the regex as the first argument and the replacement (star) as the second.
You can find more about the regular expressions and even great playground [here](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, I have worked through it and now understand it better. thank you also for the link to the playground, very useful